# Batch rename using alternating alpha suffix

Tags: batch-file, rename

I am looking to batch rename a large number of files by adding a suffix of an alpha character, but only in a specific range. For example: File 126.pdf should be renamed 126A.pdf, File 127.pdf should be renamed 127B.pdf, File 128.pdf should be renamed 128A.pdf, File 129.pdf should be renamed 129B.pdf, etc. Any existing software that is capable of doing this is also appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You don't explain which rule are used to decide for choosing the character. Btw. SO is a plattform for programming questions, not for software recommandations.

Comment: @jeb: From how I read the question, the idea is to alternately apply a fixed set of suffixes to a sorted list of files.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Define the set of replacements
for %%a in ("126=126A" "127=127B" "128=128A" "129=129B") do set %%~a
rem Achieve the replacements
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   if defined %%~Na (
      ren "%%a" "!%%~Na!.pdf"
   )
)
```

Previous program is based on the examples given in your request. Perhaps if you define the rename rules in a different, more precise way, the program may be entirely different!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET suffixes=AB
FOR %%I IN (*.pdf) DO (
  RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI!suffixes:~0,1!.*"
  SET suffixes=!suffixes:~1!!suffixes:~0,1!
)
```

The `suffixes` variable is set to an "array" of all the possible suffixes to use with renaming.

When iterating over the files, the first suffix in the array is picked to form a new name. Then the suffixes are swapped in the array, so the other one becomes first at the next iteration.

This solution will work with an arbitrary number of suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FOR loop to examine each single filename.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in (*.pdf) DO (
  echo Filename=%%A
  set name=%%~nA
  set "prefix="
  if !name! == 123 set prefix=A
  if !name! == 999 set prefix=B
  echo rename "%%A" to "!name!!prefix!.pdf"
  ren "%%A" "!name!!prefix!.pdf"
)
```